# Ebean finder returns ExpressionList

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean, web-development-server

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaEbean

according to the tutorial `Finder` should return a `List<E>`.
I tried it, but instead it returns `ExpressionList<E>`
I tried to cast it to `List<E>` but it failed.

so, the tutorial must be wrong, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `findList()` function should use in the end to make it return `List<E>`